# Why do I get exactly the same comment by different users for my link-only answer?

Tags: discussion, comments, review, low-quality-posts, link-only-answers

Since the last 2 days, I am getting a message in my [SO Inbox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/155861/diecho) with the comment below for my previous answers where I have suggested only a link as the answer.

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes

Interestingly these comments are from different users on different answers.

Is this is done automatically by Stack Overflow staff, or is that a bug?

You can see the comments on my answers linked below:

1. [see the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5103879/regex-an-enum-from-mysql/5103920#comment15962263_5103920)
2. [one more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191706/how-to-get-defined-variables-and-its-values-in-php/5191766#comment15958283_5191766)
3. [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191706/how-to-get-defined-variables-and-its-values-in-php/5191766#comment15958283_5191766)

Comment: Nope, that's just several people using the same comment text. They are probably using [AutoReviewComments](http://stackapps.com/questions/2116/autoreviewcomments-pro-forma-comments-for-se). They are correct, btw, you really shouldn't answer with just a link.

Comment: You might want to have a look [at this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers) for further information on the issue.

Comment: but all these comments are exact similar but by different users!

Comment: @PopularDemand: Interesting, that's why we are seeing that text more often now!

Comment: @Brad Thanks for the tags. i was unable to add these tags.

Comment: Aside: Why did you choose *not* to expand on your answers after being urged to do so? If you're getting those comments a lot, maybe you should listen to them.

Comment: related: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Those comments come from people who are using the new `/review-beta` page. When they review answers from the Low Quality Posts section, one of the buttons they see is **Recommend Deletion**.

Reviewers who recommend deletion get the opportunity to provide a reason. Each reason comes with a boilerplate comment that the system automatically adds to the post in question.

[image]