# Prevent duplicate auto-comments from review deletion recommendation

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, review

As seen in [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143663/why-do-i-get-exactly-the-same-comment-by-different-users-for-my-link-only-answer), when multiple people use the new canned response on a deletion recommendation in the Low Quality queue, the comments can fill up and become an echo chamber. Certainly this dilutes the message.

**Feature request**: If one of the canned comments is currently live on the post, don't add a duplicate.

Comment: Am I missing something, or do none of the examples in the question you link to have such multiple comments?

Comment: I'm sure they've been cleaned up.

Comment: Reference Question get 2 downvote whereas you got two upvote :D

Comment: Nope, each example had exactly one comment. The author was confused because each example had the *same* comment. @Bart

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is already implemented.

The author of the question you link to got three identical notifications because he had *three different answers* with the same issue (all of which are now deleted).

While this is *also* somewhat annoying, I'm going to call it [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign).

Comment: emmm if it is by design, why mark it as completed? Or if it completed, why mark it as by design in your answer?

Comment: @amanaPlanaCAnalPAnaMA he's referring to different things; completed because they are prevented, showing 3 notifications for 3 answers is by design

Comment: @BenBrocka ahhhh haaaa.

Comment: I love it when a feature is implemented before I even ask for it. Probably because that's how my managers expect me to work.

Comment: Ya, Geoff must have a crystal ball next to his keyboard.