# Three individuals have now commented the exact same comment on old answers of mine?

Tags: discussion, review

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why do I get exactly the same comment by different users for my link-only answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143663/why-do-i-get-exactly-the-same-comment-by-different-users-for-my-link-only-answer)

I have noticed that over the last few days the exact comment

> This is really a comment, not an answer to the question. Please use "add comment" to leave feedback for the author.

has shown up from three individuals I've never seen before to old answers of mine.  None seem to be moderators.

I was wondering why this is.  Is there a campaign running?  Is there a new button I've not seen for this adding exactly that as a comment?

Comment: It might be this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143669/prevent-duplicate-auto-comments-from-review-deletion-recommendation or http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143663/why-do-i-get-exactly-the-same-comment-by-different-users-for-my-link-only-answer

Answer (score 15):

This is one of the canonical reasons provided to users who are reviewing low quality posts and recommend deletion of an answer they come across. The comment is automatically posted on their behalf.

[image: This is a comment, not an answer]

It looks like the actual result doesn't match what's displayed in the dialog though. It may have changed at some point.

Answer (score 12):

When users are reviewing [Low Quality Posts](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts) (2K only), and mark any answer as "This is a comment, not an answer," that comment is automatically added for the reviewer.

And now the comment is changed to:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.