# Prevent duplicate form comments in review queues?

Tags: feature-request, bug, comments, review, duplicate-questions

**Notice:** Yes, I saw [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/143669/202832). It is not a duplicate since it is no longer accurate.

---

Take a look at [this review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/6345436) ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27202101/1234256)). It has two instances of

> While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

[According to shog](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/143680/202832), however, the prevention of duplicate form comments is already implemented.

I propose that if this is, somehow, [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign), that duplicate form comments be replaced with upvotes on the first.